# BERTopic: Probabilities are NoneType when doing supervised learning

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, topic-modeling

I'm following the guide [here](https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/getting_started/supervised/supervised.html) on how to use BERTopic for supervised learning on the `20newsgroups` dataset. I want to see all calculated probabilities so I added `calculate_probabilities=True` to the BERTopic instance, see below. However, `probs` comes up as `NoneType`. Is some dependency I am lacking or something wrong with my implementation?

`probs` does return an array of probabilities when doing unsupervised learning, so I wonder if this issue is unique to supervised learning.

```
# Skip over dimensionality reduction, replace cluster model with classifier,
# and reduce frequent words while we are at it.
empty_dimensionality_model = BaseDimensionalityReduction()
clf = LogisticRegression()
ctfidf_model = ClassTfidfTransformer(reduce_frequent_words=True)

# Create a fully supervised BERTopic instance
topic_model= BERTopic(
        umap_model=empty_dimensionality_model,
        hdbscan_model=clf,
        ctfidf_model=ctfidf_model,
        calculate_probabilities = True
)

topics, probs = topic_model.fit_transform(docs, y=y)
```